# Ofuscar Código JS ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Qual a forma mais apropriada em se ofuscar o código criado usando JS ES6 para utilização dentro do electronjs?

Comment: Quando faz o "deploy" tecnicamente fica 'inacessível', a não ser que alguém faça engenharia reversa, ou estou enganado?

Comment: Exatamente, pois se descompactar o .assar todo o código estará lá, legível. E o Uglify nao consegue trabalhar com o ES6 mesmo usndo o harmony

Comment: já experimentou o https://www.npmjs.com/package/enclose? Gera um aplicativo do seu projeto, eu realmente nunca usei, espero que sirva :)

Answer (score 0):

Eu não domino esta ferramenta (electronjs), mas para uso geral, independente do Electron creio que o que procura seja isto:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/uglify-js-es6

Para instalar (globalmente):

```
npm install uglify-js -g
```

O comando de uso seria este:

```
uglifyjs --compress --mangle arquivo-original.js
```

Adicionando vários:

```
uglifyjs src/arquivo-original1.js \
         src/arquivo-original2.js \
         -o dist/projeto.min.js \
         --compress --mangle
```

Comment: ja rodei sim mas ele.apresenta alguns problemas com require e const